# Django - can't run makemigrations: "no such table" even after running reset_db

Tags: python, django

I am unable to run `makemigrations`, `migrate`, or anything else (`flush`, `reset_db` from django-extensions) if I have a certain app in my INSTALLED_APPS.

The app is called `issues` and has one model:

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    sent = models.BooleanField()
```

And it was working before (makemigrations and migrate ran fine and I could use the app/model correctly), until I tried adding:

```
severity = models.IntegerField()
```

and tried to run makemigrations. I don't have the error or remember it anymore, but since then everything is broken, even after removing `severity` from the model.

Everything works if I remove the `issues` app from my settings.py.

The error I get:

```
madjura@madjura-E6228:~/workspace/budget/src$ python3.5 manage.py makemigrationsTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 337, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: issues_issue

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/madjura/workspace/budget/src/issues/apps.py", line 16, in ready
    issues.models.Issue.objects.check_and_send_unsent_issues()
  File "/home/madjura/workspace/budget/src/issues/models.py", line 18, in check_and_send_unsent_issues
    for issue in issues:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1087, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 835, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 337, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: issues_issue
```

While issues is in INSTALLED_APPS I get the same error when running migrate, flush and reset_db.

I have tried running flush and reset_db with issues removed from INSTALLED_APPS, this did not solve the problem.

I have tried doing the above and then running makemigrations and migrate, this does also not work. As soon as I put issues back in INSTALLED_APPS everything is broken.

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

Maybe relevant, the issue model has a Manager with a function:

```
class IssueManager(models.Manager):
    """Manager for the Issue class."""

    def check_and_send_unsent_issues(self):
        """
        Checks for unsent Issue objects (Issue.sent = False) and attempts
        to send them.
        Issues that have been sent are deleted.
        If the issue fails to be sent for whatever reason, it is not deleted.
        Does nothing if there are no unsent issues.
        This method is called once when the server starts.
        """

        issues = self.get_queryset().filter(sent=False)
        for issue in issues:
            try:
                make_issue(issue.title, issue.description)
                issue.delete()
            except PostIssueException:
                pass
```

Using apps.py I check for unsent issues and post them on Gitlab.

**EDIT 2:**

Issue resolved by commenting the line below which appears in my `apps.py`, in  `ready()`:

```
    issues.models.Issue.objects.check_and_send_unsent_issues()
```

Which somehow caused things to break, I don't understand why. Could someone explain that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the line `import issues.models` into `def ready()` to prevent loading the models too early.